# How to show/hide nested divs using *only* CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to show/hide a specific div on-click, but there are some serious caveats.  I should also mention I fundamentally know how to do this, using answers gleaned from similar questions here (eg., http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/1/), but this is more for the specific situation.

I have a CMS which will not allow me to edit the HTML *at all* outside of specific modules.  Additionally, the CMS is one of those which disables `id` selectors, so I cannot use those, either.

I  understand that the JSFiddle example I provided hinges on specific sibling/child selectors, but I'm wondering if there's a selector which would work for this situation.  I can only edit the html in the first module (for simplicity's sake, I'll call it `.module-1`), but I want to show/hide `.module-4`

The arrangement of the code in the CMS, however, is a little bit byzantine.

This is a parred down version of what I'm working with (this is for a sidebar, by the way, housed under the `beta` id).  I cannot edit *any* of the fundamental structure, except in the place marked:

```
  <div id="beta-inner" class="pkg">
    <div class="module-1 module">
      <div class="module-inner">
        <div class="module-content">
          <!-- I can edit this area only, so this is where I would place my show/hide link. If the jsfiddle method I posted is appropriate in this situation, I'm assuming it would show/hide after clicking on links placed here. -->
          <span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Module-4</span>
          <span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Module-4</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="module-4 module">
      <!-- this is the module I want to show/hide -->
      <div class="module-inner">
        <div class="module-content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can edit the CSS as much as I want, provided I don't use `id` (which has been made inaccessible to prevent people messing up the CMS?  I think that's the rationale offered), and I believe that precludes the checkbox hack entirely.

I *cannot* use JQuery/JS/anything of that nature, since they're disabled.  I know this would be a quick thing with jquery, but unfortunately, there's nothing I can do about that.

So... *if this is possible*... how would I go about doing it?

Comment: show/hide the module-4 when clicking on what element?

Comment: Added placeholder links in the ``.module-1 .module-content``; I'm _assuming_ it would be something like that, but it can be any element so long as it's able to be housed in ``.module-1 . module-content`` -- also changed the jsfiddle since I posted the wrong one.

Comment: you cannot then

Comment: i edited, indented your code and fixed comment syntax. Indentation helps you see the structure of your html tree and possible CSS selector you can used . Parent selector is not avalaible. CSS is helpless with this structure.

Comment: You can't even use inline javascript inside onclick? Only CSS is not possible.